# Sed remove text to text except last line

Tags: sed, awk

I want to delete part of text:

```
0
1
test1
a
b
random letter
test2
e
f
g
```

I want to get:

```
0
1
test2
e
f
g
```

I've tried use sed:
`sed '/test1/,/test2/d'`

But it will remove test2 too
How can I delete text and save `test2`, if I don't exactly know what text before `test2`

I need to use `awk` or `sed`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

give this a try:

```
sed '/test1/,/test2/{/test2/!d}'
```

test with your example:

```
kent$  echo "0
1
test1
a
b
random letter
test2
e
f
g"|sed '/test1/,/test2/{/test2/!d}'
0
1
test2
e
f
g
```

Answer (score 3):

```
awk 'BEGIN{p=1}/test1/{p=0}/test2/{p=1}p' your_file
```

Tested Below:

```
> cat temp
0
1
test1
a
b
random letter
test2
e
f
g
>
> awk 'BEGIN{p=1}/test1/{p=0}/test2/{p=1}p' temp
0
1
test2
e
f
g
>
```

If you want to search for whole word in awk:
search like below:

```
/\<WORD\>/
```

Alternatively you can go perl as well:

```
perl -lne 'BEGIN{$p=1}if(/\btest1\b/){$p=0}if(/\btest2\b/){$p=1}print if $p' your_file
```

Comment: But what if there will be test11 instead of test2